Variable that applies for only one user id in discord.py
So I am trying to create a stopwatch for someone when they do "/logstart" and "/logstop" but i want multiple people to be able to start and stop their own stopwatch without interference.
@bot.command(name='logstart')
async def logstart(ctx, arg1):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('Log has Started')

@bot.command(name='logstop')
async def logstop(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('FLIGHT LOG\nDuration: stopwatch time\nFlight Plan: argument1')

User does "/logstart EGCC(DEP) EGLL(ARR)":
Bot: Log Started
User does "/logstop"  
Bot: **FLIGHT LOG**  
Duration: %stopwatch time%  
Flight Plan: EGCC(DEP) EGLL(ARR)

i tried searching the docs for how to make a local variable but didn't find much

I'm assuming the issue is that you want this data to persist across multiple restarts (since you can just use a regular old dictionary to store the IDs from ctx and their respective start times!!).
Assuming you're able to read/write to wherever the bot is hosted, I would use sqlite3 as a pseudo-dictionary. Make a single table with columns for the user's ID, start time, and arg1. If size/memory usage is a concern (including for a dictionary), you can do cleanup inside the logstart() or logstop() methods. Maybe have a maximum number of concurrent timers (blocking new timers from starting) or cull any unfinished timers that were started unreasonably long ago.

So basically something like:
import sqlite3
# blah blah blah


MAX_TIMER = 259200                  # 3 day limit
DATABASE_PATH = 'whatever.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH)
cur = conn.cursor()                 # a cursor to simplify fetching/executing

# create table, ignoring error if it already exists
try:                                # (remove "PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL" if you want multiple timers per user)
    conn.execute('CREATE TABLE timers (user_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, time_started TEXT, arg1 TEXT);')
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    pass


@bot.command(name='logstart')
async def logstart(ctx, arg1):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    await ctx.message.delete()

    # if you only allow one timer per user ("PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL"), you can do the following:
    try:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO timers (user_id, time_started, arg1) VALUES(?,?,?)', 
                    (id, time.time(), arg1))
        await ctx.send('Log has Started')
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        await ctx.send('You already have a timer started')

    # maybe handle cleanup here? in this example, i delete all rows older than 3 days
    cur.execute('SELECT user_id, time_started FROM timers')
    for id, time_started in cur.fetchall():
        if time.time() - float(time_started) > MAX_TIMER:
            # maybe send a message/whisper to the affected user?
            cur.execute('DELETE FROM timers WHERE user_id=?', (id,))


@bot.command(name='logstop')
async def logstop(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    await ctx.message.delete()

    # ---

    # if you only allow one timer per user:
    cur.execute('SELECT time_started, arg1 FROM timers WHERE user_id=?', (id,))
    data = cur.fetchone()
    if data:                        # `fetchone()` returns None if no such row exists
        time_started, arg1 = data   # `time_started` is text, so make sure to cast it to a float
        duration = time.time() - float(time_started)
        await ctx.send(f'FLIGHT LOG\nDuration: {duration}\nFlight Plan: {arg1}')
        cur.execute('DELETE FROM timers WHERE user_id=?', (id,))
    else:                           # ^ delete row once we're done with it
        await ctx.send('You haven\'t started a timer')

    # ---

    # if you allow multiple timers per user (they'd need to pass `arg1` again):
    cur.execute('SELECT time_started FROM timers WHERE user_id=? AND arg1=?', (id, arg1))
    time_started = cur.fetchone()
    if time_started:
        duration = time.time() - float(time_started)
        await ctx.send(f'FLIGHT LOG\nDuration: {duration}\nFlight Plan: {arg1}')
        cur.execute('DELETE FROM timers WHERE user_id=? AND arg1=?', (id, arg1))
    else:
        await ctx.send('You haven\'t started a timer')



Some notes:

My SQLite is a bit rusty, so I'm sorry if there are any mistakes. This is hopefully good enough for you to get started though.
If you want multiple timers per user, you can get the number of timers they've started with len(cur.execute('SELECT * FROM timers WHERE user_id=?', (id,)).fetchall()) instead of fetchone()
You could also just... write this stuff to a text file everytime a timer is started. That would be just as persistent/safe and 10x easier (but far less scalable).
I really hope I didn't completely misunderstand your question, but at least I gave myself a good refresher on databases.

